# How to make adaptive dashboard layout using CSS grid

Tags: html, css-grid, dashboard

I need to make an layout for the dashboard. I don't know how many elements it will have, I don't know exactly sizes of these elements, so it isn't a static layout. It should be dynamical and proper work with a set of cards with different sizes. My idea was to make something similar to Bootstrap concept - to divide viewport on 12 rows and 12 columns, and for each card assign two classes that describes width and height of this card. I want them to be adaptive, so small elements should fill gaps if they small enough to do this. On this step, I don't want to use JavaScript, I rely on CSS only.

I made an example with 4 cards. Their summarise size is 12x12 and it looks great. But if I add one more card it is placed on the right, but I want it to be on the bottom, accessible through scroll. I understood that it is because of `grid-auto-flow: column dense`, but if I keep only `dense` my third card is placed on the right of second element, above fourth card. What do I need to change to achieve my goal? Or is it impossible at all?

This is my version:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(250deg, #fe4 40%, #0df 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-12 {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.col-4 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.col-8 {
  grid-column: span 8;
}

.row-5 {
  grid-row: span 5;
}

.row-1 {
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.row-6 {
  grid-row: span 6;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="card col-12 row-5">Card 1</div>
      <div class="card col-4 row-5">Card 2</div>
      <div class="card col-4 row-1">Card 3</div>
      <div class="card col-8 row-6">Card 4</div>
      <div class="card col-4 row-5">Card 5</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what about using grid-auto-flow: row dense